# How do I point a GoDaddy subdomain to Heroku app

Tags: heroku, deployment, dns, subdomain, godaddy-api

I have a domain name with GoDaddy: example.com.

I want example.com to point to my front-end app on Netlify (currently doing so fine with the nameservers pointing to Netlify).

I have created a subdomain on GoDaddy, api.example.com. I want to point this to my back-end app on Heroku (currently working with Heroku’s free (and rather whacky) subdomain name.

I am struggling getting my subdomain on GoDaddy to point to my app on Heorku. The DNS Target given by Heroku is to be added into the DNS. But in GoDaddy, the DNS is unable to be managed because my nameservers are already pointing towards Netlify - and it is my assumption, I cannot point a subdomain to Heroku via Netlify (unless I’m mistaken). I have checked other answers on here, but none seem to face this problem of nameservers already pointing elsehwere.

I’m pretty new to this back-end deployment, so any help would be gratefully appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: "it is my assumption, I cannot point a subdomain to Heroku via Netlify (unless I’m mistaken)"—I've never used Netlify, but you are almost certainly mistaken. Have you _tried?_

Comment: Yes, I can only create aliases on netlify.

Comment: What do you (or does Netlify) mean by "alias"? That's not a standard DNS record type (though some providers have proprietary things they call aliases). Heroku [wants a `CNAME` record](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#configuring-dns-for-subdomains), which is the closest standard DNS thing to an "alias".

Comment: @Chris maybe the author is going by this definition? https://simpledns.plus/help/alias-records
also if you try `host www.stackoverflow.com` in terminal it outputs `www.stackoverflow.com is an alias for stackoverflow.com`. Could be setting up that kind of 'alias'